# Let user post to page wall from Facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I have a Facebook app programmed within a Facebook page iFrame tab. The app contains several picture riddles. Now I want the user to have the chance to post the riddle and some text to the page wall in order to ask other fans for help with the riddle. I know that a post to the users wall is no problem, but I can´t find a solution for the above problem (app to page).

Any ideas? I would really appreciate any help on that topic.